# Twig data deeply nested - variable name lengths?

Tags: php, twig

I have a very deeply nested data structure and the variable names in my Twig template are getting quite long.

In Mustache, you can "delimit" the data using the `{{# variable }}` and everything inside that you wouldn't have to "prefix" with that variable, like this:

data:

```
variable1
    variable2
        variable2_1
        variable2_2
    variable3
        variable3_1
        variable3_2
        variable3_3
```

Mustache template:

```
{{# variable1}}
    <element>{{variable2}}</element>
    <element>{{variable3.variable3_3}}</element>
{{/ variable1}}
```

In the above, you don't have to prefix the `variable2` and `variable3.variable3_3` with `variable1`.

Here's an example of one data element that I have:
`ProcNoStsRq.ProcFold.Header.Admin.Sup.Pty.Contact.Comms.SA.Address.City`
(note that this one is shortened from the 122 characters of the real variable name)

I know I'm going to have some that are even deeper. How can I achieve the same in Twig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think think you can do this straight up, but if you use includes u could make it work.

`{% include "template.twig" with { 'variable2' : variable1.variable2, } %}`